# how do I bring my shell back in [Process completed] terminal in macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I was wonderful if I can bring back my shell when I accidentally do a ctrl + D to close my shell, when I am back from a ssh to my vps, setting terminal to [Process completed].
Plus my platform is MacOS sierra, using zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just start a new shell in an existing window. Opening a new window will start a new shell. However, you can use Terminal's restoration feature to start the shell in the same window once again by **quitting and reopening Terminal**.

[image]

Comment: Do you know where is this stored ?

Comment: The restoration state, I'm trying to remove it.

Comment: @Mathieu It's removed when you close the window, so close the window before quitting Terminal to not have it restored when relaunching Terminal. If you really want to access the location, open `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState/`.

Comment: Thanks. Deleting it would be a solution for my problem (disable state restoration)